# Display custom profile field in twig

Tags: theming

In drupal7 I used this code in my template file (node--article.tpl.php) to display the author bio. This is a custom profile field named field_author_bio.

```
<?php print user_load($uid)->field_author_bio['und'][0]['value']; ?>
```

In drupal8 I have the same setup.But I'm stuck how to do this with a twig template?

Any advise? 
Thanks.

Comment: You don't say what template this is in. If it's the user template, just `{{ content.field_author_bio }}`

Comment: O, sorry not it is not the user template. I used this code in my article template: node--article.tpl.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a pretty simple solution. I was thinking way to difficult.
It was pretty simple to make the author_bio field visible on my article pages.

All I had to do is go to: Configuration, Account settings, Manage display and select the "Compact" display (admin/config/people/accounts/display/compact). And then add author_bio. And Save. Thats all.

This way I don't need any code.

Now the author_bio field is displayed on the article page.

Thanks

Comment: Exactly..... I'm new to drupal. I don't know if this solution is correct. Because when i do it this way. The author_bio is included into the twig {{ author_picture  }}

Answer (score 0):

This is a user template from Drupal 8. Check detail [here](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21user%21templates%21user.html.twig/8.2.x) or below code.

```
{#
/**
 * @file
 * Theme override to present all user data.
 *
 * This template is used when viewing a registered user's page,
 * e.g., example.com/user/123. 123 being the user's ID.
 *
 * Available variables:
 * - content: A list of content items. Use 'content' to print all content, or
 *   print a subset such as 'content.field_example'. Fields attached to a user
 *   such as 'user_picture' are available as 'content.user_picture'.
 * - attributes: HTML attributes for the container element.
 * - user: A Drupal User entity.
 *
 * @see template_preprocess_user()
 */
#}

<article{{ attributes }}>
  {% if content %}
    {{- content -}}
  {% endif %}
</article>
```

Please see the comment code. If you want to render your custom field in template, just `content.<your_custom_field>`.
With your example is `content.field_author_bio`.

In case your field's content when rendering is not your expectation, you maybe need to use `template_preprocess_user()` for preprocessing content before rendering in the template (Search more about this function if you need).

Comment: Hello, thanks for your response, but it is not the user template. I used the old drupal7 php code in my article template: node--article.tpl.php